# Node.js: whitelisting/redaction of database entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, access-control

From node, I access a database with objects like

```
animals: [
{
  name: monkey,
  diet: banana,
  tame: false,
},
{
  name: donkey,
  diet: carrot,
  tame: true,
}
// [...]
]
```

I'd like to give access to most of the data to the clients, but make sure that the `tame` property is *not* exposed.

Using node and [lodash's `pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick), I could somehow whitelist the data, e.g.,

```
// retrieve data
// [...]

// whitelist
return {
   name: _.pick(animal, 'name'),
   diet: _.pick(animal, 'diet'),
};
```

but this is somewhat tedious, particularly if the selection of keys depends on other factors (e.g., the user who tries to access the data).

What's are good whitelisting/[redaction](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/) patterns/modules for node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of this depends on the Database you use. Most databases allow you to select only specific columns/fields in the query itself. MongoDB also does this.

If you use mongoose you can actually enforce this per model:

```
function filter(document, animal) {
    delete animal.tame;
    return animal;
};

var options = {
    toJSON: {transform: filter},
    toObject: {transform: filter}
};

var animalSchema = new Schema({
       name: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
       tame: { type: boolean, required: true },
       secret: { type: String, required: true, select: false }
    },options);


var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);

var dog = new Animal({name:"rex", tame:true, secret:"rexrex"});

dog.save();

dog.toJSON(); // will not have "tame" property
dog.toJSON({transform: filter}) // dynamic filter

dog.toObject(); // will not have "tame" property

Animal.findOne(); // result objects will not have "secret" property
```

As you see, you can:

1. Set a transform function to execute on document when exporting to json or object.
2. Mark a field with `select:false` , and it will not show up in any mongoose Model based queries. (You still can do a custom query though.)

In case you are processing a lot of objects, consider writing a [Transform Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform). Then you can:

```
Animal.find().stream().pipe(myTransformStream).pipe(clientResponse)
```